# how to add product to wishlist after login by guest customer in magento

Tags: php, magento-1.9

when i(guest customer) want to add a product to wishlist from category page or product page, after click on wishlist button redirect to login page. after sucessfull login no products in my wishlist.

After login If i again click on a product  add to wishlist then it works fine.

Please help me.
Thankyou

Comment: We have no context whatsoever to the question you're asking.

Comment: how were you able to add to the guest wishlist without login?

Answer (score 0):

use the session_id on the pc,if on the json api for android or ios,you would generate the unique_id to imitate session_id. the session_id is only on this system,generate it when open(request) the page,relation it to user after login.

Comment: when we test the live theme demo on same pc. then it works fine